# keeping the outcome file in a byte array in java

Tags: java, file, arrays

I have the below java code in which i am passing a file name abc.csv to the the calling method so that it will convert it into xls extension lets say below code is initially the code is

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc.csv");
        String filename = file.getName();
         s = getFileExtension(file) ;
         if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(".csv"))
                 {
             convertcsvtoexcel(filename);
                 }
                 FileInputStream fin = null;
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
```

now since there is an csv file that is being passed so it will call the method to convert the csv to excel

now please advise i want to customise this method of converting below so that it should return the converted file into a byte array and later on i can pass the same byte array to the later stages of code specially to HSSFWorkbook constructor  since rite now what is happening it reads the csv file from my c: and generate another .xls converted output file and keep it in my C: drive and later piece of my code again read the converted output file from my c: again , so i want to skip these repeated steps i want to attach this in sequence such that file is being read first from my c: and then converted into xls and then same .xls file is passed to later code please advise how to achieve this

```
  public static  void  convertcsvtoexcel(String filepath) throws Exception {

              ArrayList arList=null;
                ArrayList al=null;
                //String fName = file.getName();
                String thisLine; 
                int count=0; 
                FileInputStream file1 = null ;
                file1   = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath)); 

                 DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(file1);
                int i=0;
                arList = new ArrayList();
                while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
                {
                 al = new ArrayList();
                 String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
                 for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
                 {
                 al.add(strar[j]);
                 }
                 arList.add(al);
                 System.out.println();
                 i++;
                } 

                try
                {
                 HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                 HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
                  for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
                  {
                   ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
                   HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
                   for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
                   {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                    String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
                    if(data.startsWith("=")){
                     cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                     data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                     data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
                     cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
                        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }else{
                        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                        cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }
                    //*/
                 //   cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
                   }
                   //System.out.println();
                  } 
                 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Brokerage\\outputabc.xls");
                 hwb.write(fileOut);
                 fileOut.close();
                // System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
                } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                } //main method end

            }
```

Folks please advise how can i store the file in byte array please
                well I do not want that converted file .xls to be kept at my local computer C drive I want that it should be initially picked from my computer C drive then converted into xlss and that xls file on the fly is passed to file input stream itself directly

Comment: So you want to write the file to RAM instead of disk? You can do that with ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: @SpiderPig Thanks a lot you got the point can ypu please explain in detail request you to please correct my above code and make changes that will help me a lot to grasp those changes

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ByteArrayOutputStream to save the Data into a byte array and then use a ByteArrayInputStream to pass that data to the HSSFWorkbook constructor.

e.g.

```
public static byte[] convertcsvtoexcel(String filepath) throws IOException {
  ...
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  hwb.write(out);
  return out.toByteArray();
}

byte[] xlsData = convertcsvtoexcel(filename);
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(xlsData));
```

But maybe you don't even need to do that. Instead the `convertcsvtoexcel` method could just return `hwb`. Why do you want to convert your `hwb` workbook to a byte array and then back again? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: @SPiferPIg's answer well I do not want that converted file .xls to be kept at my local computer C drive I want that it should be initially picked from my computer C drive then converted into xlss and that xls file on the fly is passed to file input stream itself directly